# Endomorphism ring of semisimple modules

Tags: reference-request, modules

Can someone   help me to prove the following statement, or introduce some reference about it?

Statement: Suppose that $M$ is a semisimple $R$-module of finite type. There are division rings $D_1, ... , D_r$, such that $End_R(M)$, as a ring, is isomorphism to $\prod_{l=1}^{r} M_{n_l}(D_l)$.

thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: @Hanno Since $M$ is of finite type then there is some $n \in N$such that $M$ is isomorphic to $M_1 \oplus ...\oplus M_n$, where each $M_i$ is a simple module. so $End_R(M)$is isomorphic to$Hom_R(M_1 \oplus ... M_n,M_1 \oplus ... M_n)$. and my Shur's Lemma we know that $End(M_i,M_j)$ is adivision ring...

Comment: Yes! Now just collect the $M_i$ together according to whether they are isomorphic or not, and you're almost done.

Comment: @Hanno what's your idea about the meaning of $\prod_{l_1}^{r} M_{n_l}(D_l)$? is it the direct sum of some matrices or another product?

Comment: It's a direct product of matrix rings over division rings, i.e. you have addition and multiplication defined componentwise.

Comment: Conc. your (deleted?) comment: It depends on what you mean by the symbols $\coprod$ and $\prod$: categorically, the former means coproduct and the latter means product. Now, in the category of abelian groups, these are the same (for finite indexing sets), but in the category of rings, for example, they are not: the coproduct would be the free product, while the product would be the cartesian product with componentwise operations. It's the latter that pops up naturally here, so I'd use the symbol $\prod$ here, although, as abelian groups, you might also write $\coprod$ or $\bigoplus$.

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem almost solved.

Comment: Great, you're welcome! :)